# how to make new table columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment only a cell is added to theclicked link's row and the bottom columns are not shown.
i would like the js code below to work such that if i click onany link say link 2 none of the top cells in the column are displayed apart from starting with the one inline with this link 2 and those below in the newly created column.

```
<table id="datble" class="form" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 1</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 2</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="addColumn(this);">Add 3</a></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addColumn(element) {
    var tr = element.parentElement.parentElement;
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = '<label>Name</label>';
    td.innerHTML += '<input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />';
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
</script>
```

I have been trying out this code:

```
  function appendColumn() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        var newcell = tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length);
        for (var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't do it.
jquery is also welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/3n6YE/5/)
If I correctly understood you need something like this:

```
function addColumn(element) {
    var tr = element.parentElement.parentElement;
    var trs = tr.parentElement.querySelectorAll( "tr" );
    var trN = nInArray( trs, tr );
    var tds = trs[ trs.length - 1 ].querySelectorAll( "td" );
    var tdNextN = parseInt( tds[ tds.length - 1 ].querySelector( "input" ).name.match( /BX(\d+)_NAME\[\]/ )[ 1 ] );
    if ( trN == 0 ) {
        tdNextN++;
    }
    for ( var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++ ) {
        var td = document.createElement( "td" );
        if ( i >= trN ) {
            td.innerHTML = "<label>Name" + tdNextN + "</label>";
            td.innerHTML += "<input type=\"text\" required=\"required\" name=\"BX" + tdNextN + "_NAME[]\" />";
        }
        trs[ i ].appendChild( td );
    }
}
function nInArray( array, object ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        if ( array[ i ] === object ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution.+2 for being close.it doesn't show the lower cells .

Comment: In what browser and system? In my all 5 browsers on windows it's code appends column to the table.

Comment: It only shows the row column of the cell whose link i have clicked with the label and input,but for those cells below that it does not .Check out the answer ticked above and you'll see the difference in operation

Comment: If you click on `n` row then in `n`, `n+1`, `n+2`, etc. rows added inputs... I don't understand a question. Made a few changes to the answer was correct.

Comment: @ostapishe i can't get to see you fiddle

Comment: @user3253289 np. I can rewrite it using `jQuery`, do you need it?

Comment: @ostapishe have a look at my  next build to this  question check out this new Problem :how to assign names to new table columns cells dynamically

Comment: @ostapishe variations are good  give it to me please,but there is another development to this question have you seen  my post  on givivng names to the cells

Comment: @user3253289 there is no needs to make a new question. I'm update my answer to your needs, check this out. Is there what you want?

Comment: you were close to the solution.But the requirement is that the mother column in this case name 1 should have siblings of any column created next apart from that created when add 1 is clicked again.ie Add link 1 creates another mother always such that  we have a group with the same name .So in this case name 1 should be the name of any child column elements created by clicking on link add2 or link add3 as long as user does not click on link add1 again. if he does, then we now have  a new mother column .hope it is clear.

Comment: If on initialize I click on `Add 2` for example we must add `Name 1` column. If I'm click after it on `Add 1` we must add `Name 2` column, right? I'm update an answer, try it.

Comment: thanks it does work as i required.+2 for  this solution

Comment: @ostapishe how can i get the number of columns count up to the position of the clicked element.Iwould like to add the new column for the add link immediately next to the column containing it and not at the end only for the row containg second and any more below it .see this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qRcZN/4/

Comment: @user3253289 in function `addColumn` to get current row position use `var rowNumber = $( element ).closest( "table" ).find( "tr" ).index( $( element ).closest( "tr" ) );`. If you click on `Add` in first row it will be 1, if in second it will be 2. If you need column index use `var columnNumber = $( element ).closest( "tr" ).find( "td" ).index( $( element ).closest( "td" ) );` but it starts from 0.

Comment: @user3253289 thnks But now ,how can I use insertAfter() instead of append().I need to put the new column next to the clicked element's. I have tried this but no good:  /*get column of element clicked*/var colToHide = element.parentElement;
        var index1 = $(colToHide).index();alert(index1);trs[i].appendChild( td ).insertAfter
('#datble tbody tr td:eq(' + index1  + ')');  where can I put the variable td containing the dynamic data. according to your fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/3n6YE/5/

Comment: Try it out `td.insertAfter( $( $( $( "#datble" ).find( "tr" )[ rowNumber ] ).find( "td" )[ columnNumber ] ) )`, where `td` - yours cell. I see you appending two cells, then you need to use `td.insertAfter( $( $( $( "#datble" ).find( "tr" )[ 1 ] ).find( "td" )[ columnNumber ] ) )` for `first` cell and `td.insertAfter( $( $( $( "#datble" ).find( "tr" )[ 2 ] ).find( "td" )[ columnNumber ] ) )` for `second` cell. Or if you want to use my variant try it  http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/3n6YE/9/

Comment: ostapische it is not working at all:http://jsfiddle.net/qRcZN/5/.your variant works but the display of your refElement tds for add links..whys can;t i reference by column number and simply do an insert after the column in which the add link was clicked

Comment: I can't understood what you mean %)

Comment: ostapische Imean that you remove the link column and add it together with the inputs,and try to meke it work.Mine at the moment has failed to show thefull column from top to bottom:http://jsfiddle.net/qRcZN/19/

Comment: from the clicked parent td's column ,i would like to check if the next columns have empty tds ,but iam not able to do this.here is what I have so far:http://jsfiddle.net/eL5xvur2/14/

Comment: You have `columnNumber` you just need to calculate `input`s count in next ( `columnNumber + 1` ) column, cause you have one input in one cell.

Comment: how can i do that??here is what I have been trying so far:http://jsfiddle.net/qqkptudu/7/ but it keeps giving me a total column count instead oftelling me 0 for the next <td> not being empty.even when empty it keeps giving the same result

Comment: I'l give you a [work example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756679/how-to-make-new-table-columns-dynamically/24757122?noredirect=1#comment50597635_24757122). Why you don't use them?

Comment: No problem with working example,Iam using them to make  some variations.like placing the new column at the end of the consecutive empty td's in a particular row of the clicked link's parent row if you click fourth link,then third,then first andlastly second you'll see a problem.I have tried this so far :http://jsfiddle.net/qqkptudu/10/

Comment: igot something here: http://jsfiddle.net/qqkptudu/12/ but the problem is that it fails to get the empty cell count  when the table rows are dynamically generated from php script why is that ??

Comment: ia, trying to rename all the textareas in the table according to the column number in which they are after adding a new column: so that if it is in column 1,then it is named second1 and second3 if in column 3:I have this so far:http://jsfiddle.net/qqkptudu/15/  but it doesnot do the work:how can i adjust my resetnameandid()

Comment: Create a new question. It is not the subject of the current question.

Answer (score 1):

And that's what I think is required:

```
function addColumn(element) {
    var tr = $(element).closest("tr")[0];
    var allTrs = $(tr).closest("table").find("tr");
    var found = false;
    allTrs.each(function(index, item) { 
        if (item == tr) {
            found = true;
        }
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        if (found) {
            td.innerHTML = '<label>Name</label>';
            td.innerHTML += '<input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />';
        }
        item.appendChild(td);
    });
}
```

[Fiddle with this](http://jsfiddle.net/3n6YE/1/)

Comment: Thanks you got what I required.+3

Comment: but it does not work with the jquery-latest plugin.can you change this to javascript code

Comment: @user3253289 you mean newest version of jQuery?

Comment: i tried it on a fresh page with this:jquery-latest.js and i couldn't see any action

Comment: please send me a link to the version of jquery you used

Comment: @user3253289 in this fiddle jQuery 1.11.0 is used. jQuery 2.1.0 works aswell.

Comment: @ Regent what am i doing wrong here:$(function(){

function addColumn(element) {
 var tr = $(element).closest("tr")[0];
 var allTrs = $(tr).closest("table").find("tr");
 var found = false;
 allTrs.each(function(index, item) { 
  if (item == tr) {
   found = true;
  }
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  if (found) {
   
   td.innerHTML = '<label>Name</label>';
   td.innerHTML += '<input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]" />';
  }
  item.appendChild(td);
 });
}

});
</script>

Comment: all that is below the end of table tag, inside the body of my page.but ..no show where can i place this function outside the $(function..)

Comment: how can i rename the inputs according to the column they are in,say bx_name1[] if it is in column 1 and so on

Comment: from the clicked parent td's column ,i would like to check if the next columns have empty tds ie $("#datble td:nth-child(columnNumber+1):not(:last) & count all columns that have empty tds ie $("#datble td:nth-child(columnNumber+1):not(:last) from that parent column .and place new column there how can I loop through these tds /columns to perform this check:jsfiddle.net/t933m07f/4

Comment: @user3253289 if you have new question, you should ask it as separate question. Not only because of SO rules, but also because you have better chances to get answer in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of jquery

```
   $('#datble').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>');
   //or you can prepend
   $('#datble').find('tbody').prepend('<tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>');
```

Comment: This adds **rows** to the table, not **columns**.

Comment: you can use $('#datble').find('tr:nth-child(n)').find('td:nth-child(n)').after('<td></td>'); // or .before('<td></td>');  n must be replaced with number

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this throught jquery:

```
var html = "";
```

after

```
html += '<tr><td>TD</td></tr>';
```

or

```
html += '<tr>'; 
html += '<td>';
html += 'TD';
html += '</td>';    
html += '</tr>';
```

and after all do this

```
$('#' + table_id ).append(html);
```